# Determining object types in Qt

Tags: qtextedit, qlineedit

I have a series of QTextEdits and QLineEdits connected to a slot through a QSignalMapper(which emits a textChanged(QWidget*) signal). When the connected slot is called (pasted below), I need to be able to differentiate between the two so I know whether to call the text() or toPlainText() function. What's the easiest way to determine the subclass type of a QWidget?

```
void MainWindow::changed(QWidget *sender)
{                   
   QTextEdit *temp = qobject_cast<QTextEdit *>(sender);
   QString currentText = temp->toPlainText(); // or temp->text() if its 
                                              // a QLineEdit...
   if(currentText.compare(""))
   {
      ...
   }
   else
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

I was considering using try-catch but Qt doesn't seem to have very extensive support for Exceptions... Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, your solution is already almost there. In fact, [`qobject_cast`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qobject.html#qobject_cast) will return `NULL` if it can't perform the cast. So try it on one of the classes, if it's `NULL`, try it on the other:

```
QString text;
QTextEdit *textEdit = qobject_cast<QTextEdit*>(sender);
QLineEdit *lineEdit = qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(sender);
if (textEdit) {
    text = textEdit->toPlainText();
} else if (lineEdit) {
    text = lineEdit->text();
} else {
    // Return an error
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use sender->metaObject()->className() so you won't make unnecesary casts. Specially if you have a lot of classes to test. The code will be like this:

```
QString text;
QString senderClass = sender->metaObject()->className();

if (senderClass == "QTextEdit") {
    QTextEdit *textEdit = qobject_cast<QTextEdit*>(sender);
    text = textEdit->toPlainText();
} else if (senderClass == "QLineEdit") {
    QLineEdit *lineEdit = qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(sender);
    text = lineEdit->text();
} else {
    // Return an error
}
```

I know is an old question but I leave this answer just in case it would be useful for somebody...